# Upload de arquivos trabalhando com sockets em PHP

Tags: php, socket, file-upload, chat

Há um pouco tempo atrás, resolvi explorar e estudar um pouco de sockets para ser trabalhado em PHP.
Então peguei um bom tutorial na internet e resolvi criar um chat bem simples onde eu ligo o servidor e duas máquinas acessa o endereço para fazer a comunicação.

Depois de ter feito esse chat, surgiu a ideia de fazer um upload de arquivo no próprio chat, porém não sei se é possível, ou melhor, como posso trabalhar com arquivos dentro de um chat fazendo comunicação via socket?

Fonte que utilizei para criação do chat:

https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/

Comment: Você pode enviar os arquivos convertendo para base64, assim você os envia como texto e depois decodifica.

Comment: Ou pode simplesmente mostrar em base64 também rsrs

Answer (score 2):

Você pode enviar os arquivos utilizando base64, veja um simples exemplo de conversão utilizando php:

```
$image64 = base64_encode('caminho/da_img.jpg');
```

Para decodificar é bem simples também:

```
function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' ); 
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );
    fclose( $ifp ); 
    return $output_file; 
}
base64_to_jpeg($image64, 'novo_caminho/da_img.jpg');
```

Ou simplesmente você pode enviar como base64 e trabalhar com ele na base64 sem conversão, como por exemplo para mostrar uma imagem:

```
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($image64);
...
<img src="<?php $base64 ?>"/>
```

Assim a imagem é mostrada na tela normalmente.

Fontes:

[How to convert an image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding)

[Convert Base64 string to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

Comment: Hm, não tinha parado para pensar nisso, achei interessante a ideia. E se eu quisesse fazer upload de arquivos além de imagem, como por exemplo, subir um txt ? Funcionaria essa alternativa?